# Django-haystack: rebuild_index fails (haystack.exceptions.SearchFieldError) after adding `content_auto` line needed for autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm trying to implement yielding results for a searching only a part of a word (which is called `autocomplete` according to the Haystack docs if I'm not mistaken).

**Example:**

Search `"gol"`

Result `"goldfish"`

**What have I tried?**

I did as asked in [step 1 of the docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/autocomplete.html#step-1-setup-the-data), I added the following line in my Index class:

```
content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')
```

Then did `python manage.py rebuild_index`.

*Rebuilding the index however produced an error* `haystack.exceptions.SearchFieldError: The model '<Person: Reginald>' does not have a model_attr 'content'.` With `Reginald` being the first entry in my indexed table and `Person` being the model I indexed.

Now indeed my model doesn't have a field called `content` but as it is shown in the docs it should not need to have such a field.

I am using `Whoosh 2.4.1`, `Django-haystack 1.2.7` and `Django 1.4`.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. I didn't work on the problem for long though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is how I'm solving this right now.

Instead of:

`content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')`

Use:

`content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(use_template=True)`

Then you can create a template for these. For example, I have an `ItemIndex` in my `catalog` app, where I want to search `name` and `description`. So, I made a file in `templates/search/indexes/catalog/` called `item_content_auto.txt`, which has the following in it:

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
```

This seems to be functioning how I want it to. A little more tedious than if `'content'` worked, but it should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated example for reference (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26570873/6748184)):

```
#search_indexes.py
class Book(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Book

#template
{{object.name}}

#query
SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(text=my_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

model_attr is used to reference an existing model attribute, callable or relation:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/searchfield_api.html#SearchField.model_attr
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchfield_api.html#model-attr

Comment: Yes, but see this: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/autocomplete.html They say you just need to use 'content', but that doesn't work. They must have changed it and not updated the docs.