# Unescape search results with django haystack and elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack with elasticsearch backend. The data contains names of books that may contain special characters like `&`, `'` or `""`. The indexed data escapes these characters and the search results shows the escaped data. How do I tell haystack or elasticsearch to

1. turn off escaping 

   OR
2. unescape the characters when I want to use the results in a non-HTML context i.e. as plain text ?

Here's my code:

```
#search_indexes.py
class Book(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Book

#template
{{object.name}}

#query
SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(text=my_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template you can use filters and tags like:

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ object.name }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

or

```
{{ object.name|striptags }}
```